# Grabbing Header Link response using ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, http, http-headers

I'm trying to grab the Link header from a API response.

[image]

```
 $.ajax({
            type  : "GET",
            url   : "url_here"
            cache : false,

      }).done(function( data, status, response ) {
          var headers = response.getAllResponseHeaders();
```

I get the following response,

```
cache-control: no-cache
connection: Keep-Alive
content-length: 528
content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
date: Fri, 27 Aug 2021 14:39:47 GMT
keep-alive: timeout=5, max=92
server: Apache/2.4.41 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.0.2s PHP/7.1.33
x-powered-by: PHP/7.1.33
```

Comment: Is this a cross-origin request? The available headers are limited by CORS.

Comment: @SamR Yeah it is, is there no solution round this? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is a small set of [default allowed headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/CORS-safelisted_response_header) when making a cross-origin (CORS) request:

- Cache-Control
- Content-Language
- Content-Length
- Content-Type
- Expires
- Last-Modified
- Pragma

Though the list clearly varies, based on the response you are seeing.

The browser cannot change the list, but it can be managed *by the server* using the header [Access-Control-Expose-Headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/)